# Error en getSelectedItem para luego enviarlo a un jTextArea

Tags: java, combobox

Lo que deseo hacer es que cada vez que se seleccione un ítem de mi `ComboBox`, su evento `itemStateChanged` recoja el ítem seleccionado y luego lo envíe al `JTextArea`.

Pero cuando lo quiere mandar al `JTextArea` el ítem seleccionado se envía duplicado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilicé en el evento `ItemStateChanged` del `ComboBox` es el siguiente:

```
String usu;
usu = cbAgregar.getSelectedItem().toString();        
txtUsuariosAsignados.append(","+usu);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `itemStateChanged()` se dispara cada que el ítem cambia su estado,  *seleccionado o no seleccionado*; por debajo de la mesa se trabajan dos constantes, `DESELECTED` (valor entero 2) y `SELECTED` (valor entero 1).

***¿Porque se ve reflejado 2 veces el mismo ítem en el*** `JTextArea`***?***

Al hacer click sobre el ítem, este esta sin seleccionar, el evento se dispara y agrega al `JTextArea` la info de ese valor, acto seguido al "soltar" ese click, nuevamente se dispara el evento `itemStateChanged()` porque ahora naturalmente el ítem esta seleccionado.

Conociendo este comportamiento, es posible evitar agregar 2 veces la misma información simplemente distinguiendo una de las dos constantes anteriormente mencionadas: `SELECTED` y `DESELECTED`.

```
cbAgregar.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
      String usu;
      usu = cbAgregar.getSelectedItem().toString();
      txtUsuariosAsignados.append(","+usu);
    }
  }
});
```

... o bien, es valido via `ActionListener`:

```
cbAgregar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String usu;
    usu = cbAgregar.getSelectedItem().toString();
    txtUsuariosAsignados.append(","+usu);
  }
});
```